# How do I selectively print from a file using radio button input?

Tags: php

I'm attempting to make a single-page PHP page that reads from a radio button selection the user will have made earlier and uses that to search through a file and print the information that lines up with that slot of the file information, but I can't get it to actually print. I have no idea if it's just that it isn't reading the file right, isn't searching through the file right, or anything else that might be wrong, so sorry in advance if it's something really obvious.
Each line of the file has 4 bits of information on it, all with commas between them: the location, the location type, and two numbers. Here's the first line: Roatan,Natural Reef,28,41. I'm attempting to use the first bit, the location, to search through, since that's what the radio buttons are based on. I hope that's enough info.

```
<input type="radio" name"site" value="Roatan"> Roatan <br /></input>
```

This is what the radio buttons are formatted like, and it's all in one form tag with the submit button.

```
foreach ($dives as $i=>$record) {
        $dives = explode(",", $record);
        if (($site == "Roatan") and ($record[0] == "Roatan")) {
            print "<tr>
                <td> $dives[0] <br /></td>
                <td> $dives[1] <br /></td>
                <td> $dives[2] <br /></td>
                </tr>";
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

And this is what the loop and conditionals look like.

Comment: First off, your radio should use `name="site"`. Secondly, your loop makes no sense because you're assigning to `$dives` while that's the name of what you're looping through. I'd give the temporary name within the loop a name like `$dive` instead. If neither of these solve the issue, you haven't given us much to work with...

Comment: For future reference, I would put your file in a json format, and then in php use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

You should also checkout [PHP's regex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment, you have a typo.

This should get you started though.

**example script:**

Run from the command line with `php -S localhost:8000 index.php` and access from your browser with http://localhost:8000.

```
<?php
// filename: index.php

$chosen_site = isset($_POST['site']) ? trim($_POST['site']) : null;
$file = "Roatan,Natural Reef,28,41\n Some,Thing,32,42\n Value1, Test, 89, 90";
$results = "";
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 900px;
            /*text-align: center;*/
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .fail {
            color: red;
        }
        .pass {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Results</h1>
        <hr/>
        <p><b>You Chose:</b><?= json_encode($chosen_site) ?></p>
        <?php
        // For each line of the file.
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            //Print result of each line:
            if(strpos($line, $chosen_site) !== false) { 
                echo '<p class="pass"><b>Match found:</b>';
                echo '<ul>';
                $parts = explode(',', $line);
                foreach ($parts as $part) {
                    echo '<li>'. $part . '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p class="fail"><b>Match not found: </b>' . $line . '</p>';
            }
        }
        ?>


        <h1>Form</h1>
        <hr/>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="site" value="Value1">Value1</input>
            <input type="radio" name="site" value="Value2">Value2</input>
            <input type="radio" name="site" value="Value3">Value3</input>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```